# Can range structure be used as a user input in Swift?

Tags: swift, console-application, swift5

I want to write a program in Swift for macOS (console app) which will take two intervals from user and output basic operations on them like union, intersection and difference which distinguishes between closed and open interval.

My problem is that I have no idea how to make a readLine with ranges, and because of the new Swift 5 version there is little info about Range structure.

Should I use ranges or different structure / type?

For example:
Input: 

`[-10,3)
(2,+∞)`

Output:
`Union: [-10,3) U (2,+∞) = [-10, +∞)
Intersection: [-10,3) ∩ (2,+∞) = [2,3)
Difference: [-10,3) \ (2,+∞) = [-10, 2)`

Comment: Is your question about creating ranges from the string input or is your question about performing the actual operations on the ranges?

Comment: You probably should define and work with your own interval type. Swift has a “closed range“ `a...b`  and a “half-open range” `a..<b`, but  for example nothing which corresponds  to an open interval (a,b) or (a,+∞).

Comment: @rmaddy the first one

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use some custom type (struct/class) for this to easier represent infinity and to apply the specific interval operations. I also assume there's a difference between ( and [ that might needs to be translated into a property (or logic)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I thought that „range” is the type of structure you are talking about hence the question. Thank you for the answer, I assume i should make a class that will do that.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I have no idea how to make a readLine with ranges

There is not some magic built-in way.

You have essentially invented or imposed a notation that the user must use. The user input, however, is just a string. It is up to you to parse the user input and see if / how it conforms to that notation. Building a rigorous parser is a big subject.

A better solution might be to build a user interface that allows the user to construct, visually, the kind of object you are asking for. For example you might have a choice of interval type and a box for lower bound and a box for upper bound. Things like infinity would also be entered visually rather than making the user learn to type an infinity symbol. So too for choosing an operation to apply to multiple ranges, such as intersection.

Behind the scenes, on the other hand, the mathematics will be pretty trivial, as Swift Ranges give you just about everything you need right out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don’t know if I understood: should I make a Single View App that will visually show the user operations on ranges that he will choose? Then there is no input like in Console App?

Comment: My answer covers both possibilities. I understand you propose to do this purely as a console app, like a command-line tool. If that's what you want to do, fine; then you just have text input and, as I said, you must hope the user uses correct notation and you must parse it from the ground up. But I'm also suggesting that it is easier for the user and for you to give your info entry an _interface_ that helps and guides the user and you. What is a "better" way to write a calculator: emulate a desk calculator with buttons, or make the user type equations and you have to parse them as string?